# How to publish a file only once? ASP.NET vNext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have a config file which contains version of some client. I need publish this file only once, and it should be same after every publish of web app. How can I do it? 
I use Visual Studio Online for continuous deployment and after every push web app in the qa server is updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Web Deploy](http://Web%20Deploy) to publish your web app.

> By default, Web Deploy determines which files need to be copied to the
>   server by comparing the dates that the local files were last changed
>   against the dates that the server files were last changed. If you use
>   a source control system that changes file dates when you check out
>   files, it appears that they have all changed, and Web Deploy copies
>   them all to the server when you publish.
>
> An alternative for this scenario is to configure Web Deploy to use
>   file checksums to determine which files have changed. Use checksums
>   only if file dates are unreliable indicators of what has changed,
>   because comparing checksums takes more CPU processing time than
>   comparing dates.

Or:

> You can limit the files that are deployed by selecting the Only files
>   needed to run this application or All files in this project options on
>   the Package/Publish Web tab. If you select the All files in this
>   project option, you can right-click a file in Solution Explorer and
>   select Exclude From Project to keep it from being deployed. For more
>   information about what files are excluded when you use the Only files
>   needed to run this application or All files in this project options,
>   see Why don't all of the files in my project folder get deployed?.
>
> If these options are not flexible enough for you, another option is to
>   edit the .pubxml or the .wpp.targets file and add an
>   ExcludeFilesFromDeployment element or an ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment
>   element (or both) in the PropertyGroup element. In each element, you
>   can specify a single name, or you can specify multiple names delimited
>   by semicolons (;), as shown in the following example: